# Does C's ternary conditional operator create a new scope?

Tags: c, scope

The title basically says it all, but I am specifically interested to know if the following (slightly abusive) macro should be expected to work (with C99 or greater), that is, that it will return a pointer to a valid section of stack allocated memory based on the size of the expression:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define NASTY(expr) ( \
    8 == sizeof(expr) ? (void *)(&(uint64_t){(expr)}) : \
    ( \
        4 == sizeof(expr) ? (void *)(&(uint32_t){(expr)}) : \
        ( \
            2 == sizeof(expr) ? (void *)(&(uint16_t){(expr)}) : (void *)(&(uint8_t){(expr)}) \
        ) \
    ) \
)
```

EDIT:

The reason I am interested in such a macro is (1) I am a a nerd and (2) I am writing some code-generating macros for an embedded application that need to dynamically `memcpy` the result of an expression (such as `x*y+z`). We are working in an energy sensitive application where function calls matter.

Comment: give some usecase example.

Comment: I mean this nicely, but why does this question need to be posed with a macro? Why is the preprocessor relevant? Or are you exploiting expression statements, which are not standard c?

Comment: Also why would ternary operator relevant? You are just taking an address of *something* .

Comment: @EOF: Compound literals **are** lvalues. You can take their addresses.

Comment: How is scope a matter of an expression?? You actually want to know "what is a scope".

Comment: Yes, @Olaf and others I did in fact mean the lifetime of the object. My C terminology is a little loose. :)

Comment: The basic entity of C's syntax is expression. An expression has no "scope". you might be confused.

Comment: That's much the same. How are expressions related to the lifetime of objects other than what functions called guarantee? C is not C++, there are no intermediate objects (again: apart from what functions do with pointers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "a new scope" - in C, "scope" is relevant only to identifiers, not object lifetime. Per 6.5.2.5 Compound literals,

> If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block.

Thus, if you use this macro inside a function body, the lifetime of the pointed-to object will persist until execution of the enclosing block ends. This might or might not meet your needs; you could get in trouble by writing:

```
if (foo) {
    p = NASTY(bar);
}
/* ... */
/* Do something with p */
```

Comment: This is exactly the behaviour I expected based on some Dr. Memory tests. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @Olaf: There's no such thing. `static` is not part of a type; it's a storage class. Putting `static` in the parentheses for a compound literal is just a syntax error.

Comment: @R..: Thanks for the info. I know what `static` grammatically is. I was just too lazy to check the grammar for compound literals if it allows storage class specifiers. I just could see some usage in that if the pointer is taken (but then, after getting some sleep, one can use a `static` variable as well, so it would be more syntactic/grammatical sugar).